# Eliminating duplicate lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a set which should hold a bunch of unique list items:
This is how I'm trying to define it.

```
results = set([], key= self.comparator)
```

This is the comparator function,

```
def comparator(self, l1, l2):
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return -1
    i = 0
    while i < len(l1):
        if l1[i] != l2[i]:
            return -1
        i += 1
    return 0
```

This  throws the following error,

```
TypeError: set() does not take keyword arguments
```

Clearly the set constructor doesn't accept the key,
If I don't pass the key, then I get the following error,

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Thus the way I'm trying to eliminated duplicate lists is not working. How can I do it in Python.

Comment: Why did you think the `set` constructor would accept a key?

Comment: Set only accepts a single argument, which is an iterable such as a list, but no other arguments are accepted is the issue.

Comment: You just cannot store lists in a set. Try tuples.

Comment: You cannot pass arbitrary arguments to python function. You need to write a custom data structure or use something like a list or tuple to hold your lists.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show some sample data and how you're calling the your function. Please read [**_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your lists into tuples to do what you want:

```
my_lists = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
tuples = [tuple(l) for l in my_lists]

print(set(tuples))
```

Seems to achieve what you need.

Prints:

```
set([(1, 2), (1, 2, 3)])
```

Comment: This could be shorted to: `uniques = set(tuple(l) for l in my_lists)`.

Answer (score 2):

Like you figured out, `set` does not accept a key like this. It does however expect whatever you bring it as items, to be "hashable", which actually means that it has a `__hash__()` method. `list`s do not have a working hash, as you can see from this example:

```
a = 'a'
a.__hash__() # prints -8546348471933684759
a = [1,2,3]
a.__hash__() # will throw TypeError
```

If you were to define a new class that acts like a list but has a unique hash based on it's values, you could use `set` on it.

```
class mylist(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        return sum(item.__hash__() for item in self)

a = mylist([1,2,3])
b = mylist([1,2,3])
c = mylist([4,5,6])
unique_lists = set((a,b,c))
print(unique_lists) # prints {[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]}
```